# Avoid PCL Reference Assemblies not installed error in mono

Tags: c#, mono, portable-class-library

I have a mono install (from tarball) and while compiling a solution received this error:

```
/monopath/lib/mono/xbuild/12.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : PCL Reference Assemblies not installed.
```

Does anyone know how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

The package referenceassemblies-pcl should be installed for PCL compilation support - this will resolve most cases of “Framework not installed: .NETPortable” errors during software compilation.

see this link: [Usage](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#usage)

Comment: What does "PCL" mean? And what exactly are you talking about? I can't find any package "referenceassemblies-pcl" here.

Comment: "referenceassemblies-pcl" is a mono specific package not distributed by Ubuntu, right?

Comment: Yes. Which concludes: Ubuntu monodevelop is broken. You need to add the mono ppa regardless (!) of version differences between your Ubuntu release and the OS target of mono.